# The gzip compressor is not going with the while loop

Tags: java, jdbc, gzip

I am trying to query from database with Java JDBC and compress data in one column  to gzip file in specific directory. I have tested my JDBC query and it working fine, but the Gzip code not going with the while loop, it's run with the loop firt row and stuck there. Why it's stuck? help me please!
These folders already existed:  D:\Directory\My\year\id1\id2

```
//Some query JDBC code here, it's work well. I query all rows Data, year, id1,id2,id3
 while (myRs1.next()){

        String str = Data;
    File myGzipFile = new File("D:\\Directory\\My\\"+year+"\\"+id1+"\\"+id2+"\\"+id3+".gzip");

    GZIPOutputStream gos = null;
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
    gos = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(myGzipFile));

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        gos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        System.out.print("done for:"+id3);
    }


    try { gos.close(); } catch (IOException e) { }
}
```

Comment: How does it get stuck? What's the error. Why don't you try printing the IOException

Comment: Sorry, i mean the Gzip code make the loop stopped when it ran the first row. The result is 1 file Gzip was created and:"BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)"

Comment: I think it's stuck here: because the Data is null. But how to make it go over null data? while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        gos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        System.out.print("done for:"+id3);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the source like this to catch exceptions.

```
public class InputStreamDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      InputStream is = null;
      int i;
      char c;

      try{
         is = new FileInputStream("C://test.txt");

         System.out.println("Characters printed:");

         // reads till the end of the stream
         while((i=is.read())!=-1)
         {
            // converts integer to character
            c=(char)i;

            // prints character
            System.out.print(c);
         }
      }catch(Exception e){

         // if any I/O error occurs
         e.printStackTrace();
      }finally{

         // releases system resources associated with this stream
         if(is!=null)
            is.close();
      }
   }
}
```